# How to call subroutines with parameters from unix shell

Tags: perl, unix, command-line

I am working with different subroutines of a Perl script.
It is possible to call a single subroutine from the Perl script via the Unix shell like:

**simplified examples:**

`perl automated_mailing.pl inf`

then the function `inform_user` from `automated_mailing.pl` gets called.
This is realized through a dispatch table:

```
my %functions = (
  inf=> \&inform_user,
);
```

`inform_user` looks like

```
sub inform_user{
    print "inform user: Angelo";

    ...some other stuff...
}
```

The question now is, how to replace "Angelo" with a variable and call it from shell like:

```
sub inform_user{
    my ($to)=@_;
    print "inform user: $to";
}
```

This call does not work:

`perl automated_mailing.pl inf("Brian")`

How is this be done correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You need to pass the arguments as separate command-line parameters:

   ```
   perl automated_mailing.pl inf Brian
   ```
2. You need to pass the command-line parameters onto the subroutine that you call:

   ```
   my ($func, @args) = @ARGV;

   # And then later...

   if (exists $functions{$func}) {
     $functions{$func}->(@args);
   } else {
     die "$func is not a recognised function\n";
   }
   ```

You haven't shown the code for the actual use of the dispatch table - so my second point is a bit of guesswork.

Answer (score 0):

With the given hint i reached exactly what i wanted.
the programm now looks like:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

sub inform_user{
    my @to = @ARGV;
    print "inform user: $to[0]";
}

my %functions = (
  inform_user=> \&inform_user,
);

my $function = shift;

if (exists $functions{$function}) {
  $functions{$function}->();
} else {
  die "There is no function called $function available\n";
}
```

and the output is:

```
>> perl automated_mailing.pl inf Brian
>> inform user: Brian
```

Comment: I'd really recommend passing `@ARGV` as a parameter when calling `$functions{$function}->()` rather than using it as a global within the subroutine.